# UITableViewCellStyle

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I would like to create a table like the iPhone (calls) which are displayed three labels.

`UITableViewCellStyleSubTitle` displays only two options as well as `UITableViewCellStyleSubValue1`.

Do I have to manually create it?

Thanks.

/ / English Google

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A third place to put something is the `accessoryView`, which shows up to the right of the cell.

The best way to have full control over a cell is to make a custom UITableViewCell. An [example](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/04/easy-custom-uitableview-drawing.html).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to manually create it. Watch [this YouTube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CGvs1XqTae0) for a tutorial.

Also, next time you ask a question, provide a more descriptive title, and you will likely get more views and answers.

Answer (score 0):

As Peter DeWeese was saying you have to make a custom UITableViewCell. 
Let me point out that since iOS 6 this is the only correct way to do it.

1. Make a subclass UITableViewCell.
2. In the initializer (.m file) you can rewrite the style that is given when the super class is called.

code example:

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
  {
  self = [super initWithStyle:--------UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle-------      reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
  if (self) {
      // Initialization code
  }
  return self;
  }

  1. Go to your TableViewController and registrate that cell in the viewDidLoad method.

  [self.tableView registerClass:[---------FriendCell---------- class]    forCellReuseIdentifier:@"vriendCel"];

//And if someone would help me out to put my code properly, can't seem to fix it. :)